# spring form with object who contain list

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a object which contains:

```
String title
List<String> paramList
List<Address> addressList
```

Address contains `int` and `string` fields storing number and street name.

I use Spring MVC and I would like to create a jsp to iterate this object. For object with list, I would like to add a button to support new entries. My problem is I don't know how to iterate this list in spring mvc tag

```html
 <form:form action="saveUser" modelAttribute="UserToAdd">
     <label for="title">Title: </label>
     <form:input path="title" />
     <label for="paramList">Param:  </label>
     <form:input path="paramList" />
 </form:form>
```

i don't know if i need to do a loop.

Comment: Then definitely you need to learn spring from any tutorials to find out how to handle the list object. Also you have to learn what are all the options available to iterate the list object in spring as well jsp.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to accept the **title** and **paramList** from user on the JSP and pass it back to controller to create the object, then try capturing these values in a session object inside JSP and retrieve them by using **HTTPSessions** object inside controller.
And for this object i would suggest have it as a view class.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate the `paramList` you could use the `<c:forEach>` loop like this:

```
 <form:form action="saveUser" modelAttribute="UserToAdd">
     <label for="title">Title: </label>
     <form:input path="title" />
     <c:forEach var="param" items="${UserToAdd.paramList}" varStatus="status">
         <label for="paramList-${status.index}">Param:  </label>
         <form:input id="paramList-${status.index}" path="paramList[${status.index}]" />
         <br/>
     </c:forEach>
 </form:form>
```